# Should it cost less than $12,000 to replace a bathroom and cast iron pipes in 1960s home?

Tags: bathroom

I need some advice please before I make a decision on hiring a contractor. 1960's home with walkout basement needs a small bathroom gut & cast iron plumbing replaced. All of the plumbing is visible on the ceiling of the basement except for what drains into the underground line of course.

Because of leakage there is flooring and a joist missing under the tub which all needs to be replaced. I have $12,000 saved for project, is this a reasonable expectation?

Comment: $12k to replace a joist? That seems like plenty.

Comment: Replacing all the cast iron plumbing for a single leak seems a bit over the top - it should have another 50 years in it, unless you have some particularly nasty corrosion issues you have not mentioned or described. Is the tub leak from the tub drain, or due to a pipe failure? Are there other signs of failure in the main drain pipes? If not, leave them alone and they will likely outlast you.

Comment: To give any kind of advice we would need to see pictures of everything.  Even after pictures there is huge variance but we need to see pictures.

Comment: I think she wants to gut the bathroom and redo it. That means new toilet and shower. New shower. Maybe some electrical work also. As such, I am thinking that 12,000 is not enough. It also depends on what small means and what kind of tile he wants to put in. Also, if she is located in a major city, such as NYC, then the prices will be higher.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to know what is involved from the vague description. I can't even understand whether the bathroom is above the basement or in it from your description.

Generally speaking, minor structural repair on a house might cost anywhere from $500 to $2,500. Replacing free-standing sewage pipes might cost $400 to $800. If things (like the house itself) need to be lifted or moved out of the way, costs can go up. Usually minor structural changes can be made without lifting though.